# Kotlin enum map

Tags: kotlin, collections

Is it possible to create such a map that is granteed to contain all enum keys as its keys?

Here is what I'm trying to achieve but with null-safety garanteed.

```
enum class Product { A, B }

private val _products = mapOf<Product, MutableLiveData<Int>>(
    Product.A to MutableLiveData(),
    Product.B to MutableLiveData()
)

val products = mapOf<Product, LiveData<Int>>(
    Product.A to _products[Product.A]!!,
    Product.B to _products[Product.B]!!
)
```

**Update**

The maps construction can be simplified like this.
Thanks to @Michael for tha second line.

```
private val _products = Product.values().associateWith { MutableLiveData<Int>() }
val products: Map<Product, LiveData<Int> = _products
```

This solves the issue of construction a map with all enum keys, but yet does not let one get a value without non-null assition:

```
val a: Int = products[Product.A]!!.value
```

Comment: Wouldn't `val products: Map<Product, LiveData<Int>> = _products` suffice?

Comment: It does partially. Check the updated question please.

Comment: Event if `products[Product.A]` was guarateed to be non-null, the `value` property of a `LiveData` is still nullable. So `product[Product.A].value` would still be an `Int?`. I'm not quite sure I understand why it is important for `products[Product.A]` to be non-nullable, considering how easy it is to deal with null-values in Kotlin(?). For example `val a: Int = products[Product.A]?.value ?: 0`

Comment: The nullability of the LiveData value is not important here. I just need to be able access map value itself. Both !! and ? are reduntent here, so just wanted to find out if there are any other solutions for this.

Comment: Well, it's still not entirely clear to me how you're going to use these product collections in your actual code and why dealing with null-values is a problem. But you could e.g. add the livedatas as properties to the enums and skip the maps entirely. It's hard to say what would work best without having seen how the data is going to be used.

Comment: The use case is quite simple. The collections are owned by a ViewModel. The first one is private for setting values and the second one is open for LiveData subscribers. Your first comment solved the major problem. The null-safety is not that much of trouble now, but the code would look cleaner without the reduntent use of !! and ?

Comment: It’s kind of a code smell to want to inspect the `value` if you’re not doing it to use it as a basis for determining the next value. LiveData is for observing. But you can subclass MutableLiveData to have it return a non-nullable type with a default non-null value to fall back to. Then to avoid the nullability when fetching from the value, you can use `getValue()` instead of `[]`.